How do fix ImgBB API sending image problem?
I am trying to send images using the ImgBB API, but I always receive a failure message, regardless of the type of image.

import fetch from "node-fetch";
import FormData from "form-data";

const API_KEY = process.env.IMAGE_BB_API_KEY;
const api = `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload`;

const uploadImage = async (base64) => {
  if (!API_KEY) {
    throw new Error("IMAGE_BB_API_KEY - required");
  }
  if (!base64) {
    throw new Error("base64 - required arg");
  }

  const imageData = base64.substr(base64.indexOf(",") + 1);

  const form = new FormData();
  form.append("image", imageData);
  const url = `${api}?expiration=600&key=${API_KEY}`;

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: form
  });
  const imageResponse: any = await response.json();

  try {
    return {
      imageurl: imageResponse.data.image.url
    };
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("failed to send image");
  }
};

export default uploadImage;


import imgbb from "./imgbb";

const uploadImage = async (base64) => {
  if (!base64) {
    throw new Error("base64 - required arg");
  }

  return await imgbb(base64);
  
};

export default uploadImage;


I tried using different images, but I think the problem lies elsewhere, as the error message doesn't match the code. Can someone help me with this?

"The error message doesn't match the code - Which error? You didn't provide any. If you are talking about the message in the provided screenshot, "Failed to send message", then you need to log the actual message - catch (err) {  throw new Error("failed to send image");  } - Please [edit] the question and provide the real error (as text)
